# What expression do you use in a CV if you have redone something?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I am writing my CV at the moment and I am at a tricky part.

I have redone a software for a company and I want to include this in my CV.

I have in my CV: "Erstellung eines Warenwirtschaftssystems in Visual Basic", although even this does not quite cover this.

They had an old system using Basic or something and I used a modern language, Visual Basic (don't trash me on that — I was young and needed money).

What would be the expression in correct English?

Comment: I hope you pay more attention to proper capitalization on your CV than on ELU. (Well, actually, I hope you pay more attention to proper capitalization everywhere at all times.)

Comment: very grateful for the advice, i am very, very bad at correct writing. I usually have a proofreader.

Comment: i was seriously considering posting my whole CV here, but i don't know if that is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Refactored](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) - is the word normally used for the same language
- [Rewrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_%28programming%29) is the word used if you write it in a new language

> I rewrote an inventory management system in Visual Basic from the older xxx language

Answer (score 3):

I would propose

- **rewrite**, e.g. *Rewrote legacy application in VB.* This means you took the existing application and expressed it freshly from the beginning.
- **reimplement** (or re-implement), e.g. *Reimplemented legacy system in VB.* This carries a larger sense than *rewrite*, that you updated other parts of the technology stack, for example.
- **refactor**, on the other hand, is more limited than *rewrite*, and means you restructured or extended the code to make it more efficient or usable, but not necessarily that you replaced it.

Answer (score 2):

You can say ***"Upgraded and converted an old ERP system to Visual Basic"***

Comment: Just me, but I'd avoid the word _upgraded_, lest the reader misinterpret the accomplishment as a reinstallation of someone else's software.